# MUI-Datatables adding a button next to table title

Tags: reactjs, mui, mui-datatable

Is it possible to add a button next to the MUI-datatable title?

Something like:

```js
<MUIDataTable
    ref={ref}
    title={() => (<div><Button>Click Here</Button>Table Title</div>)}
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    options={options}
/>
```

With the code above, the title is empty.

What I want to achieve is something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, it should be:

```
<MUIDataTable
    ref={ref}
    title={<div><Button>Click Here</Button>Table Title</div>}
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    options={options}
/>
```